# Why $\bar{d_0}$ is injective in a minimal free resolution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

If $(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is a Noetherian local ring, $A$ a finite $R$-module. Let $L.:\cdots\rightarrow L_1\xrightarrow{d_1} L_0\xrightarrow{d_0} A\rightarrow 0$ be a minimal free resolution. $\bar{d_i}$ is the map $L_i \otimes k \rightarrow L_{i-1} \otimes k$ induced by $L_i \xrightarrow{d_i} L_{i-1}$. Why $\bar{d_0}$ is injective?

Comment: *A priori*, it is  surjective.  Unless you mean $\bar d_0$ is injective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, in a minimal free resoluion, we begin by choosing in $A$ a *minimal* set of . If the number of generators is $n$, we define a linear map from $L_0=R^n$ by mapping the canonical basis of $L_0$ onto the generators.

Now, by *Nakayama's lemma*, this minimal set of generators yields a basis of the vector space $A\otimes_Rk$, hence the quotient map $L\otimes_Rk\to A\otimes_Rk\;$ remains surjective, and as the vector  spaces have the same dimension, it is indeed an isomorphism.

Comment: Thank you. I am still confused about the definition of minimal free resolution. I am wondering if the condition of $im(L_i \rightarrow L_{i-1}) \subseteq \mathfrak{m}L_{i-1}$ in the definition indicates that $imd_0\subseteq \mathfrak{m}A$.

Comment: Since $d_0$ is surjective, $\bar d_0$ is too, so it can't be $0$, unless $A$ itself is $0$.